# Is it possible make a tray based Electron app for handling a node ws server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, electron

I'm trying to make a websocket server that will run from a nice tray icon with a few options for stopping/starting etc in the context menu. I'm using the [npm module ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) for the server.

If I start my ws server from Electron's main process it works absolutely fine but if I start it from the click callback of Electron's tray menuitem the server's start callback never fires, as far as I can tell.

```
tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, '/icon.png'));
tray.setToolTip("Title");
tray.setContextMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: "Start Server", click: () => { startServer(); } }
]));

function startServer(){
    new ws.Server({ port: 4837 }, () => {
        console.log("Server started.");
    });
}
```

Comment: Right, the one that says console.log("server started.") never fires. or at least, never shows up in the terminal

Comment: Alright, can you put a breakpoint there?

Comment: Unfortunately I could never get vscode's debugging to work

Comment: Well I would suggest you sort that out first. Or try using electron's [`dialog`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md) to alert a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I kind of figured this out by setting a flag from the tray click handler and catch that flag in an interval at the end of js file to start the server.

My best guess, this is some weird thing to do with the process/thread that the tray is handled in.

With some more investigating it seems I can start the server by calling a bound function. Not sure why.

```
tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, '/icon.png'));
tray.setToolTip("Title");
tray.setContextMenu(Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: "Start Server", click: startServer.bind(this); }
]));

function startServer(){
    new ws.Server({ port: 4837 }, () => {
        console.log("Server started.");
    });
}
```